# Angular ng-change in input textbox with old value

Tags: angularjs, textbox, angularjs-ng-change

```
<input type="text" id="exampleab"
ng-model="a.b"
ui-event="{ blur : 'callScriptThenServer()' }" >
```

For some reasons the `ng-change` on textbox is not working so i am using it; Using Angular-ui's `ui-events`.

## PROBLEM

I want to call the function only if the **value is changed** and **also want the old value in callback**.(since I want to send the oldValue to the server).

I don't want to go via pure directives route because there are so many occurrences of these

NG-CHANGE : on each character changed i get a callback . I don't want that. I need to call the server script .. with the old value in the text box and the new value after blur

Comment: ng-change works just fine. Check this [example] http://plnkr.co/edit/UVG8rPhBa5vrwn6UR7hr?p=preview

Comment: you will need to type something in the box to use that example. on change it will alert

Comment: on tying each character i get a callback .. I DON't WANT THAT .. i need to call the server script .. with the old value in the text box and the new value after blur

Comment: ng-change was not working since i was using old version of ngularjs

Comment: okay great, now you have new angularjs just use ng-blur= instead of ng-change= so that when user has finished with the input the value will be sent to the server (note in some cases users will type a character and switch to next input for that you need to implement a chekc inside your controller)

Answer (score 17):

You can watch your variable to have the newValue and oldValue at the same time.

```
<input type="text" id="exampleab" ng-model="a.b"  >
```

In your controler:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('a.b', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('oldValue=' + oldValue);
        console.log('newValue=' + newValue);
        //do something
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/T3m8Z/3/show/)

**EDIT**
You mentioned a new requirement in your edit so i edit my answer.
You shouldn't use ng-change. you should get the oldValue when the control being focused and save it in a variable and then get the new value on blur event.
[**I set up a new fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/64NVR/17/)

In your controller :

```
    app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.showValues = function () {
            alert('oldValue = ' + $scope.oldValue);
            alert('newValue = ' + $scope.a.b);
        }
    });
```

I your view

```
<input type="text" id="exampleab" ng-model="a.b" ng-init="oldValue = ''" ng-focus="oldValue = a.b" ng-blur="showValues()" />{{a.b}}
```

Comment: on tying each character i get a callback .. I DON't WANT THAT .. i need to call the server script .. with the old value in the text box and the new value after blur

Comment: @naveen23: You need to work on your writing, which sounds really rude and unthankful.

Comment: @phresnel Why does he need to? When people does not read his requirements correctly... Its his waste of time...

Comment: @Elisa: If a partial misunderstanding in the effort of __helping__ some _stranger_ __for free__ justifies being rude and aggressive in your world, I am glad we are not friends. You don't even realise that it's especially the __answerers__ waste of time if there's a misunderstanding, __not__ the askers. -- edit: OTOH, your opinion does no longer surprise me after seeing your 1/10 answer/ask ratio, or more specifically 1/40 with actual upvotes. This time, seemingly an indicator of non-experience in donating some free time. Are you a [parasite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitism)?

Comment: @Alborz Thanks a lot for such a great solution. I was playing with ng-change. Now I replaced it with ng-focus and ng-blur events. It works fine. I'm getting old and new values. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 10):

Use ng-model-options

```
<input type="text" ng-model="a.b" ng-change="callScriptThenServer()" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**AngularJS Watch**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch)

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return $scope.a.b;
}, function(newvalue, oldvalue){
    //Here You have both newvalue & oldvalue
    alert("newvalue: " + newvalue);
    alert("oldvalue: " + oldvalue);
},true);
```

[**Plunkr DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7PikFmEQk0akQy1mOFSR?p=preview)

Comment: on tying each character i get a callback .. I DON't WANT THAT .. i need to call the server script .. with the old value in the text box and the new value after blur

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular ngModelOptions with getterSetter:true; and then use method call inside the "set" part of the function.

See the last example on this page:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions